# Half Bridge Driver shorting the output of the circuit

Tags: power-electronics

This is a follow up question for this [first one.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/297339/choosing-resistor-values-to-operate-a-half-bridge-driver) Please read the original question before proceeding. I'm making all wiring on a bread board.
At the output of the inductor (from the previous question), I connected a 100uF (the calculation was 50uF) electrolyte capacitor. The inductor used is an 1.48mH [RFS1317-155KL](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/597/rfs1317-774541.pdf). The resistors used are 72 ohms as recommended in the previous question. 
As I connect the input to 12V, I start the higher side MOSFET voltage at 0 and increment it by .1V. as I reach .9V the output of the supply indicate a short circuit. The output of the Half Bridge Driver without any voltage at the Vgs of the MOSFETs is shown below, with green being the gate at the lower side MOSFET and yellow being the gate at the higher side MOSFET:

[image]

as I zoom in on the dead-band, I see this:

[image]

With sharing grounds from the supply to the micro-controller and the half bridge driver IC. I'm assuming the that the output of the half bridge driver is affected by noise coupled to the loops and many ground connections, causing that jitter of around 3V at the switching times, which is above the MOSFET's threshold value, making a short circuit. Does this look like an EMC problem? should I go for PCB instead of a bread board?

MOSFET used: [IRL60B216](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRL60B216_datasheet-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625acbae4c015add6de3df168f),

Half Bridge Driver: [IRS2003(S)PbF](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irs2003pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535675afec2780), with input of 15KHz from the micro-controller's Timer.

Comment: What are the values for DCR or 1.48mH L2, and ESR of C's used and Req load and load switch frequency if not DC then source switch rate is 15kHz

Comment: DCR=1.36  Ω, ESR=? Load Req=0.5~1 Ω?? or is it LEDs with ESR of <<0.5  Ω?

Comment: Cant tell if they are or not, but your IRS ground needs to be close to the half bridge ground. Also, attach your scope ground there too to minimize scope grounding artifacts. Of course moving the IRS ground may cause issues with the digital side, but one thing at a time.

Comment: Where are your 100mV Vcc or MOSFET ground current sense shunt scope pictures? Can you do this?  Make sure to use very short probe ground leads or none with 1cm wire from barrel and tip!!  Wave shows 20Mhz scope ground lead cable resonance . Must  do like this for <10ns risetimes http://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/rigol-ds1054-needle-spikes-true-or-false/?action=dlattach;attach=159007;image

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a measurement problem due to rapid change in impedance of half bridge with drive signals rated at 400ns dead time or DT (+/-20%)

[image]
This dead time may reduce with Rg*Ciss choices of your FETs and may increase if you use additional parallel diode R in parallel with Rg to control fast turn off and slower Turn on.

This a common method and must be factored with load current being switched off and Dampening factor of load for low Q.

[image]

### Solution:

use only this measurement method, Make or buy adapter.
[image]